# Internalization for client components in NEXTjs

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next

I'm working on project where I need to translate content in 4 different languages. I have watched lots of tutorials and tried several solutions but everytime I'm getting stacked to the same problem.
Inside my app I have a lot of "use client" components that I need to translate, but dictionary that I use for translation works only as a server-only component.

Exanple of dictionary.ts:

```
import 'server-only'
import type { Locale } from '@/i18n.config'

const dictionaries = {
  en: () => import('@/dictionaries/en.json').then(module => module.default),
  de: () => import('@/dictionaries/de.json').then(module => module.default)
}

export const getDictionary = async (locale: Locale) => dictionaries[locale]()
```

When I run my app I get an error:
You're importing a component that needs server-only. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.

In all of the tutorials that I watched, people were showing simple examples without any hooks, so they didn't get this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a provider component in your base formatter near the top of your view hierarchy. This provider loads and caches the server language dictionaries at startup and is shared with the client environment. A detailed solution is here:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/57405

Comment: Please do not reference external sources